# Drupal: issue with choosing the files to upload

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've an issue with uploading files with Drupal CCK fields.

The issue is client-side. When I click on the "Choose File" button in my browser, all the files in my "Choosing file" operating system popup window are disabled.

It was working before, and for example the extension ".png" is written below the field, so I know it is accepted, but the file is disabled and I cannot select it.

Quite strange.. do you have any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this too. See [this ticket](http://drupal.org/node/939102) for details. Fixed in FileField and ImageField 3.8.